# jQuery alerts and escaping quotes

Tags: jquery

I have a php page on which I show a jQuery alert when a user adds products to their cart. The message displayed in the alert is a variable from a php page where all language elements are stored.

```
$cartaddeditem='The product was added to your cart.\r\n You can view your <a href=\'cart.php?action=show\'>shopping cart</a> or click OK to continue shopping';
```

Then, on the page:

```
<body onload="jAlert('success', '<?=$cartaddeditem?>', '<?=$minicart?>');" <? } >
```

The problem is that the alert fails to fire because of the quotes in the $cartaddeditem var and I'm getting an error in firebug that says:

```
Error: missing ) after argument list
Line: 1, Column: 22
Source Code:
jAlert('success', The product was added to your cart.\r\n You can view your <a href=\
```

How do I escape the quote in the message string for jQuery? I tried several escaping types with double and single quotes, one or two backslashes but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using double quotes to quote your HTML attributes.

```
$cartaddeditem = 'The product was added to your cart.\r\n You can view your <a href="cart.php?action=show">shopping cart</a> or click OK to continue shopping';
```

May I also suggest not adding `onload` attributes and using `$(document).ready(` instead?

```
$(function(){
    jAlert('success', '<?=$cartaddeditem?>', '<?=$minicart?>');
});
```

**UPDATE**:
You can also use `json_encode` to make sure that quotes don't clash.  `json_encode` works on strings too, it outputs a a string surrounded by double quotes (so don't add quotes around the parameter).

```
$(function(){
    jAlert('success', <?=json_encode($cartaddeditem)?>, <?=json_encode($minicart)?>);
});
```

Comment: @NiftyDude how is that correct? You need to use `json_encode` for that, what if your string will containt `don't` or `NiftyDude's` ? You can't always avoid single quotes.

Comment: @meze: In this particular situation, this solution will work.  `json_encode` could he helpful, I guess.

Comment: @meze notice the so far? This is so far the answer that meets OP's requirement, and using that message he has. If you are using `json_encode`, don't you need to change the implementation of `jAlert`?

Comment: @NiftyDude: `json_encode` works on strings too, no need to change `jAlert` at all.  `$a = 'I\'m testing: "cool"';  echo json_encode($a); // "I'm testing: \"cool\""`

Comment: @NiftyDude when you `json_encode` a string, why would `jAlert` have to be changed?

Comment: @bikey77: Oops, didn't realize that  =/ Though, in your situation, `json_encode` really isn't needed, you can do without it.

Comment: @meze: `json_encode` *isn't* the solution here, it adds slashes to the `\r\n`.

Comment: I used json_encode and moved the jAlert into the jquery  document.ready method.
Also, changed \r\n to <br /> and it works fine. Thanks to all!

Comment: @bikey77 because your `$cartadditem` variable is single quoted, but you probably want double quoted. see my answer 'Update 2' as well

Comment: @Jack: If you change the quotes around the string, make sure to use the correct quotes around the `href` :-P

Comment: @Rocket haha yup I did. I copied his string for reference which had single quotes for HTML attributes ;-)

Comment: @Rocket  `echo json_encode("hello world \r\ntest"); = "hello world \r\ntest"`. `\r\n` in single quotes is not a new line, they're just 4 characters.

Comment: @NiftyDude I'm sure he will use the same solution in other cases too. And don't forget other people can come here with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Properly escape your PHP output:

```
<body onload="jAlert('success', 
  <?php echo json_encode($cartaddeditem); ?>, 
  <?php echo json_encode($minicart); ?>);" <? } >
```

**Update**

Because it's written inside a tag attribute, the double quotes wouldn't work (thanks Rocket)!

So you'd either have to hope `addslashes` is enough:

```
<body onload="jAlert('success', 
  '<?php echo addslashes($cartaddeditem); ?>', 
  '<?php echo addslashes($minicart); ?>');" <? } >
```

Or you do what Rocket described in his answer.

**Update 2**

Btw, you should change your PHP strings to double quotes so that `\r\n` gets evaluated as a newline:

```
$cartaddeditem = "The product was added to your cart.\r\n You can view your <a href='cart.php?action=show'>shopping cart</a> or click OK to continue shopping";
```

Comment: This won't work as written.  `json_encode` outputs strings surrounded by double quotes, so double quotes in double quotes won't work.

Comment: @Rocket after reading my answer again I realized that it's in HTML mode ... doh! ... thanks for the pointer!

Comment: The OP commented on my answer and pointed out that `json_encode` adds slashes to the `\r\n`, making it `\\r\\n`.  `addslashes` does this too =/